# Join tables in bigquery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

Hello I have 5 tables in bigquery as below

```
activity    activity_date   activity_time       userID  value
walking     2023-03-11      2023-03-11 14:00:00 abc     32
walking     2023-03-12      2023-03-12 14:01:00 abc     45

activity    activity_date   activity_time       userID  value
running     2023-03-11      2023-03-11 14:00:00 abc     12
running     2023-03-12      2023-03-12 14:01:00 abc     22

activity    activity_date   activity_time       userID  value
swimming    2023-03-11      2023-03-11 14:00:00 abc     56
swimming    2023-03-12      2023-03-12 14:01:00 abc     77
                
activity    activity_date   activity_time       userID  value
cycling     2023-03-11      2023-03-11 14:00:00 abc     54
cycling     2023-03-12      2023-03-12 14:01:00 abc     32
                
userID  age height  weight  
abc     43  170         98  

userId  fav_activity    freq_activity   schedule
abc     running         walking         10:00
```

The above tables have same activity_date, activity_time (each minute record) and userId. I want to all table based on matching columns and display walking, running, swimming, cycling values for the given date as below. Lastly join with 'user' and 'fav_activity' table

```
activity_date   activity_time   userID  age height  weight  walking.value   running.value   swimming.value  cycling.value

2023-03-11  2023-03-11 14:00:00 abc 43  170 98  32  12  56  54
2023-03-12  2023-03-12 14:01:00 abc 43  170 98  45  22  77  32
```

Please suggest how the join can be achieved in bigquery

inner join and subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can give you the expected result.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(t1.activity_date, t2.activity_date) AS activity_date,
  COALESCE(t1.userID, t2.userID) AS userID,
  t1.walking_value,
  t1.swimming_value,
  t1.running_value,
  t2.cycling_value
FROM (
  SELECT 
    activity_date, 
    userID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'walking' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS walking_value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'swimming' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS swimming_value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'running' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS running_value
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY activity_date, userID
) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    activity_date, 
    userID,
    value AS cycling_value
  FROM table2
  WHERE activity = 'Cycling'
) t2
ON t1.activity_date = t2.activity_date AND t1.userID = t2.userID
ORDER BY activity_date, userID;
```

Output :

| activity_date | userID | walking_value | swimming_value | running_value | cycling_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-11 | abc | null | null | null | 12 |
| 2023-03-12 | abc | 32 | null | null | null |
| 2023-03-12 | xyz | 45 | null | null | null |
| 2023-03-18 | xyz | null | 12 | null | null |
| 2023-03-19 | def | null | 33 | null | null |
| 2023-03-19 | xyz | null | null | null | 22 |
| 2023-03-20 | abc | null | null | 21 | null |
| 2023-03-25 | def | null | null | null | 54 |

As I don't have any free tool to show the output in BigQuery; I am trying to show the same in [DBFIDDLE demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/pwX7SAQm) using SQL Server with different Datatypes than Bigquery. However; The above query shall work in Bigquery.

Based on update :

```
SELECT
  w.date,
  w.time,
  w.userID,
  w.value AS walking_value,
  r.value AS running_value
FROM
  `your_dataset.walking_table` AS w
JOIN
  `your_dataset.running_table` AS r
ON
  w.date = r.date
  AND w.time = r.time
  AND w.userID = r.userID;
```

Updated Query for multiple tables :

```
    SELECT
  w.date AS activity_date,
  w.time AS activity_time,
  u.userID,
  u.age,
  u.height,
  u.weight,
  w.value AS walking_value,
  r.value AS running_value,
  s.value AS swimming_value,
  c.value AS cycling_value,
  f.fav_activity,
  f.freq_activity,
  f.schedule
FROM
  `your_dataset.user_table` AS u
LEFT JOIN
  `your_dataset.walking_table` AS w
ON u.userID = w.userID
LEFT JOIN `your_dataset.running_table` AS r
ON u.userID = r.userID AND w.date = r.date AND w.time = r.time
LEFT JOIN `your_dataset.swimming_table` AS s
ON u.userID = s.userID AND w.date = s.date AND w.time = s.time
LEFT JOIN `your_dataset.cycling_table` AS c
ON u.userID = c.userID AND w.date = c.date AND w.time = c.time
LEFT JOIN `your_dataset.fav_activity` AS f
ON u.userID = f.userID;
```

Comment: Thanks very much Tushar, your query works straightway. Only the amount of rows I am getting is much more than I expected so wondering if using right kind of join. May be I ask you with simple example first. If first table just have one activity 'running' and second table 'walking'. In a particular day (2023-03-11) both table has 1439 records, one record for each minute. Activity_date, UserID columns on both tables are exactly same for join condition, only value is different. What kind of join will work for 1439 rows output with (activity_date,userID, running_value,walking_value). Inner join?

Comment: Please let me know if I have to edit my question @Tushar, thank you.

Comment: `Only the amount of rows I am getting is much more than I expected so wondering if using right kind of join` : You are expecting single record per user, per day; Right ?

Comment: `In a particular day (2023-03-11) both table has 1439 records, one record for each minute` : Can you tell me few sample `Activity_dates`. If dates are same, UserIDs are same, Only minutes in dates are different; then we can group by Date excluding minutes

Comment: But, If `Activity_date` is different, `UserID` are different; Above is the only way to show:
`per day one record per user if it exists in either of the table`

Comment: activity activity_date activity_time                 userID value
walking 2023-03-11 2023-03-11 14:00:00 abc         32
walking 2023-03-12 2023-03-12 14:01:00 abc         45
    
activity activity_date  activity_time                   userID   value
running 2023-03-11        2023-03-11 14:00:00 abc           12
running 2023-03-12        2023-03-12 14:01:00 abc           22
    
    
activity_date activity_time                 userID walk.value run.value
2023-03-11 2023-03-11 14:00:00 abc         32                 12
2023-03-12 2023-03-12 14:01:00 abc         45                  22

Comment: Sorry not allowing me to edit the question so I put the sample tables in comment. I will try again editing after sometime.

Comment: No Problem Tushar, I have updated the actual question as well with sample tables. Thanks very much

Comment: One question though; You will still have `swimming` and `cycling` values, Right ?

Comment: They are in different tables actually. I have multiple tables to join. Each table is based on one particular activity and have data for each minute every day for multiple users. I have to join all those tables to get one big table. I gave you only 2 tables to join to understand the logic. Thank you

Comment: I have updated the answer and added a new query in update section; Please let me know; if it works for you. Please feel free to ask anymore questions you have

Comment: Awesome Tushar, that query worked for me and fetched accurate result. One last question to complete my query. I need to 3 more tables to the result set. 2 of them are same activity tables for (swimming and cycling). What would be the final join condition joining all 4 activity tables?

Comment: If you can give me the tables names; I can give you the query. However; it will be a general join which shall work in most of the relational databases too

Comment: Awesome Tushar, that query worked for me and fetched accurate result. One last question to complete my query. I need to add 3 more tables to the result set. 2 of them are same activity tables for (swimming and cycling). What would be the final join condition joining all 4 activity tables? Also at last, I want to join a dimension User table having 4 fields (userID,age,height,weight) so final output table should look like as below:                                           activity_date, actiivity_time, userID, age, height, weight, walking_value, running_value, swimming_value, cycling_value

Comment: If you have same users present across all tables and not missing in any of the table; you can replace `left join` with `inner join` in above query

Comment: Hi Tushar, perfect query is working fine in my environment. Only last scenario I am thinking if any of the activity table does not have data for a given activity_date or activity_time, the join condition will fail? Instead, can we put NULL?

Comment: Hi @Awssylearn; `if any of the activity table does not have data for a given activity_date or activity_time` : We are handling it with `left join` as in query in answer; So that; it should not fail.
Please feel free to ask anytime, if you face any issues

Comment: Oh okay, thanks Tushar. I will test it thoroughly tomorrow and come back to you if any questions. Have a good rest of your day.

Comment: Hi Tushar, query working perfectly, thank you. Lastly I am trying to add another dimension table 'fav_activity'. Same as 'user' table, this also has 'userId' column which can be used to join. Wondering where in the JOIN condition I can fit in this table. Table has 3 fields which I want to display (fav_activity, freq_activity, schedule). Could you please help me last time to update the final query including this dimension table. I have updated the table definition in the question. Thanks Tushar.

Comment: Awesome mate, work like magic :) This finishes my first set of work, thank you very much for your assistance. I need another help in different SQL code where I want to convert minutes data into 15 minutes, hourly and daily and calculate the sum. I will open another question for the same, hope you will pick up that too if you have time :) Appreciate your help !